# Average with small types

Tags: c++

I want to write a generic averaging algorithm. That is, for any type T that has an operator+ (T) and an operator/(float), I would like to find the average of T's in a container:

Something like this works fine for float-ish types:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::value_type RunningAverage(const T& v)
{
  typename T::value_type vectorRunningAverage = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
    vectorRunningAverage = (v[i] + i*vectorRunningAverage)/(i+1);
    }

  return vectorRunningAverage;
}
```

I could change

```
  typename T::value_type vectorRunningAverage = 0;
```

to

```
float vectorRunningAverage = 0;
```

and then it would work with a type like unsigned char (can't add more than a few unsigned chars and store the result in an unsigned char without overflow) because it can be implicitly converted to float. However, if I have some more complicated types (say I want to average the components in a `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >`, this doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing? Or does it just not make sense to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should let the caller to explicitly mention the desired return type:

```
template<typename T, typename ResultT = typename T::value_type>
ResultT RunningAverage(const T& v);
```

I also think you should take begin & end iterators rather than the entire container, as it will make your function more generic (you could then get the average of the front half of a vector, for example).

Comment: Good idea about providing the return type as a template parameter. This way I can do a similar thing with types that are not mutable (i.e. a type from a library or a STL container style type, etc). 
Also, ok, I'll make it take iterators.

Answer (score 2):

So what you need is somehow define for your type `T` what is the type containing the averages of values of `T`.

C++ traits provide clean and unintrusive solution.

```
template <class T>
struct average
{
    typedef float type; // could be or could be not sane default, depends on the domain
};
```

Then, for types that require "tuning" you just provide specialization (partial or full) for `average<>` template:

```
template <>
struct average<double>
{
    typedef double type; // want more precision
};

template <class T>
struct average<MyMegaType<T> >
{
    typedef MyMegaType<T>::value_type type;
};
```

Than the sgnature of your function could be

```
template<typename T>
typename average<T::value_type>::type RunningAverage(const T& v);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This will work for types like MyMegaType that I have defined, but for types that I cannot change (i.e. a type from a library or from my example of averaging a vector<vector<unsigned char> >, it isn't possible to add a 'typedef ... type' to vector<unsigned char>. I think I'll go with John Zwinck's solution of providing the return (and internal) type via another template parameter.

Comment: I think you didn't get it. You should not add anything to `vector<unsigned char>` to make `average` trait for it. The beauty of traits is that yo *don't need* change existing types to add this typedef -- you just define specialization for that types.

Comment: I think you're right, I did miss the idea of traits. I tried this: http://ideone.com/fZ26B but I get this error: error: no match for call to ‘(average<unsigned char>) (std::vector<unsigned char>&)’ . Any suggestions?

Comment: Your specialization for `unsigned char` doesn't contain definition for `operator()`: you need to implement all members of a template specialization that you use.

Comment: In this case I would not put any member-functions to `average` traits, but only typedefs. Then I would implement generic functor that will use the traits.